# Not sure if i'm getting the Description attribute correctly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a separate class that I would like to get the "Description" attribute:

```
public class Fruits
{
    [Description("The green apples are very green.")]  
    public const string Apples= "Green";

    [Description("Sunkist oranges are very sweet.")]  
    public const string Oranges= "Sunkist";

    [Description("Red grapes are make for wine.")]  
    public const string Grapes= "Red";
}
```

For arguments sake, I have a separate class that i want to retrieve the Description. 
So the chunk of code looks like:

```
        Type fruitType = typeof(LotsOfFruits.Fruits);

        FieldInfo[] fields = fruitType.GetFields();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", field.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", field.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());
            List<System.Attribute> attr = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)).ToList();
        }
```

The name and value fields are pulling correctly.
I got stumped at getting the Description attribute. 
At this point i'm wondering if that's the correct way (i.e. put it into a list).

Any suggestions or recommendations to get the description attribute?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  I can populate the attr value just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, but you need to cast the DescriptionAttribute as it comes out as a base Attribute class.  Also, I tend to get the first or default unless I know that I may have multiple.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type fruitType = typeof(Fruits);

        FieldInfo[] fields = fruitType.GetFields();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", field.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", field.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());
            var attr = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)).Cast < System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", attr.Description);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Fruits
{
    [Description("The green apples are very green.")]  
    public const string Apples= "Green";

    [Description("Sunkist oranges are very sweet.")]  
    public const string Oranges= "Sunkist";

    [Description("Red grapes are make for wine.")]  
    public const string Grapes= "Red";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  
i needed to cast it. Ugh. I don't know what I was thinking. 
I wish I could thank all of you guys for your advice since they all made sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your context, but by reading your code it seems you would be better of subclassing a class Fruit with Name and Description properties:

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }
}

public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public string Name { get { return "Apple"; }
    public string Description { get { return "The green apples are very green."; }
}

public class Orange : Fruit
{
    public string Name { get { return "Orange"; }
    public string Description { get { return "Sunkist oranges are very sweet."; }
}
```

Other than that your code seems right.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine; all you need is:

```
var attr = (DescriptionAttribute)field.GetCustomAttribute(
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
if(attr != null) Console.WriteLine("Desc: {0}", attr.Description);
```

Or in later .NET versions:

```
var attr = field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
if(attr != null) Console.WriteLine("Desc: {0}", attr.Description);
```

Comment: As far as I can see, both overloads of this extension method are new in .Net 4.5.